# Conflicting information in different points - is it false advertising if one is wrong?

Tags: contract-law, england-and-wales, consumer-protection, any-jurisdiction, false-advertising

Adam purchased a battery from eBay where the product image contains the eye catching text 40000mAh. But the product description in much Plainer typeset mentions that it is a 10ah battery.

Adam receives the battery the next week and finds that it is 10ah when he had wanted to buy a 10ah battery. Was Adam misled by the trader by their misrepresenting the product?

Does contra proferentum apply or some other principle?

Comment: Seems that he got the battery he wanted, so under the ordinary meaning of "mislead", he wasn't misled. What am I missing? This would be clearer if you put up a picture of the ad.

Comment: Sounds like an ambiguous ad, rather than a misleading one, if the person ordering it saw both statements. Not clarifying the issue would count against liability.

Comment: Given that 40000 mAh = 40 Ah (amp-hours), this might be clearer if you stick to Ah throughout.

Comment: Adam purchased a battery. Adam received a battery. Who is Bob?

Comment: Sorry thought I’d change it up a bit because apparently people get sick of hearing about Bob but old habits die hard it seems. See edit history.

Comment: @ohwilleke sorry if it wasn’t clear. Whether or not Adam had noticed both would seem a question of fact and let’s suppose he is claiming that he didn’t notice both but only noticed the more bold, colourful and eye catching inaccurate spec. The focus of the question is on the status of a vendor giving conflicting information in multiple places.

Comment: Sorry everyone, did not sleep very well last night.

Answer (score 7):

> [Adam receives the battery the next week and finds that it is 10ah when he had wanted to buy a 10ah battery.](https://law.stackexchange.com/revisions/96834/3)

[Reliance on the erroneous information is a necessary element to a misrepresentation claim](https://cunningtons.co.uk/reliance-in-misrepresentation/). Since Adam *actually* wanted what the plainer typeset described (the 10ah battery), and then received that same thing (a 10ah battery), there is no claim in misrepresentation, no matter how egregious the misstatement in the image.